# Exposing configurable argument (Port) at build

Tags: docker, .net-core, port

I want to dockerize a NET Core Application.

However i do not know how I can provide the `port` as a `command-line` argument to further use it in the `Dockerfile` like:

`ENTRYPOINT ["appname","[port_argument_from_commandline]"]"`.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest AS base
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","DockerContainerDaemon.dll" ]
EXPOSE 20000   //how can i set this as a command-line argument?
```

**Further clarification**: I want to provide my image with a configurable argument in our case lets say `port`.Then i want when i run an instance to set this argument with a value:

`docker build myapp`
 //configured to accept a command line argument named `port`
`docker run port=[instance port] myapp`

Comment: Well if i lets say expose a  `port` e.g `25000` inside the `Dockerfile`.How can i then run multiple instances of this image since all will be exposing the same port?

Comment: IME, there are a couple of details like file paths and port numbers _inside the container_ that make no difference.  Pick something and document it.  If the operator wants a different port published, they can `docker run -p 8080:25000` to pick their own external port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [build-time variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) when running `docker build`:

```
 docker build --build-arg PORT=XXXX .
```

Inside your `Dockerfile`, you can use this setting with `ARG`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest AS base
ARG PORT # Supports a default, e.g. ARG PORT=5000
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/publish /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet","DockerContainerDaemon.dll" ]
EXPOSE $PORT # Use $PORT here
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the EXPOSE instruction does not actually expose the port, but works as a documentation between the dockerfile writer and the user. Source [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

To expose a port, you'll need to pass the following option to your command line

> -p hostPort:containerPort

So in your example it could look like :

> -p 8080:20000

The whole command could look like

> docker run -ti -p 8080:20000 image_name
>
> docker run -ti -p 8081:20000 image_name
>
> docker run -ti -p 8082:20000 image_name

This would work properly and let you have 3 instances connected at the same time.

Comment: I know that when calling `docker run` you have to `host port: container port` but i did not know how you can use the `port` parameter inside the `Dockerfile` if  you for example want to run `ENTRYPOINT ["appname" ,"[port_argument]]"`

Comment: I try to be careful in SO answers about distinguishing “exposing” ports (“flag it so that `docker run -P` will allocate a port for it and the archaic link feature works”) from “publishing” them (“make this port actually accessible from outside Docker space”)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that docker-compose uses EXPOSE for something. Yeah, EXPOSE lets multiple containers defined in one docker-compose talk to each other, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801773/3406189 So EXPOSE isn't just documentation but for a single container it can't do anything.