# Forwarding parameters and ports from docker-compose to dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i am currently running a container from a `dockerfile` that uses some arguments and ports.

My question is: Does `docker-compose` override the port that i `expose` in the `dockerfile` ?

```
FROM  microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","Server.dll","arg1"]
EXPOSE 8202
```

**Docker-compose**

```
services:
  mp:
    image: mp
    build: ./mpserver
    ports:
      - 8202:8203   <-----lets say i change the left side in the dockerfile
```

In my situation `compose` can alter parameters inside the `dockerfile`(s)? (`8202` in `dockerfile` and `8203` in compose)

Can i set parameters like the arguments of `ENTRYPOINT` in the compose that would get somehow `injected` in the `dockerfile` ? (in our case `arg1`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between docker-compose ports vs expose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801772/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-compose-ports-vs-expose)

Comment: TL;DR: `EXPOSE` is mostly just documentation and you can publish whatever `ports:` you choose with whatever host mapping you want, regardless of whether what's mentioned in the Dockerfile.