# Connect to a remote Database that live in Docker via Mac OS X

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, psql

I'm on a **Mac OS X**, and have a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  portalmodules:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8010:8000
    links:
      - database
  database:
    image: postgres:11.2
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=john"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=api"
```

I also have a **Dockerfile**

```
FROM composer:1.8.5 as build_stage

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN composer install


FROM alpine:3.8
RUN apk --no-cache add \
php7 \
php7-mbstring \
php7-session \
php7-openssl \
php7-tokenizer \
php7-json \
php7-pdo \
php7-pdo_pgsql \
php7-pgsql
COPY --from=build_stage /src  /src
RUN ls -al
RUN set -x \
addgroup -g 82 -S www-data \
adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data
WORKDIR /src
RUN ls -al
RUN chmod -R 777 storage
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

The container seems to **build and start** successfully when I ran `docker-compose up`.

But when I tried to connect to the database:

- IP: localhost
- Port: 5432
- UN : john
- PW : 12345

I kept getting

[image]

How would one go about and debug this further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By specifying a port in the `expose` configuration, you're only opening that port to other Docker containers in the Docker network. It will not be open to connect to from your host machine (OS X).

You want to add a [`ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) configuration, which allows you to map host machine ports to the container.

```
database:
  image: postgres:11.2
  expose:
   - "5432"
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  environment:
    - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345"
    - "POSTGRES_USER=john"
    - "POSTGRES_DB=api"
```

[More information in this helpful StackOverflow Q&A.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801772/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-compose-ports-vs-expose)