# In a docker service, how do I share one port publicly and one port privately?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am building a docker service which includes a squid and an icap service.
Squid runs on port 3128 and this port is public.
The ICAP service runs on port 1344, which I do not want to be public, as this will contain decrypted web traffic. I want this accessible only to squid, which is the icap client.

My question is, how do I set this up so that port 1344 on the e2guardian service is running on a private network that is accessible by squid, but not published where anyone on the "customer" network can use it?

I am including my docker compose file.

The "squidnet" network is really kind of a leftover. I wonder if I can make squidnet private and then share 1344 on squidnet only, but still have 3128 public for the squid service public on the local LAN. How would I change the docker compose file to accommodate this?

Thanks

```
version: "3"
services:
  squid:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: jusschwa/docker-squid-sslbump-rpi   
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
      - "/workspace/etc/squid/squid.conf:/usr/local/squid/etc/squid.conf"
      - "/workspace/certs:/usr/local/squid/ssl"
    ports:
      - "3128:3128"
    networks:
      - squidnet
  e2guardian:
    image: jusschwa/e2guardian-rpi       
    ports:
      - "1344:1344"
    volumes:
      - "/workspace/etc/e2guardian:/etc/e2guardian"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - squidnet 
networks:
  squidnet:
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `expose` if you dont want to publish the ports to host machine. When you use `ports` it is publishing the ports to host machine.
[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801772/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-compose-ports-vs-expose)

Mapping container's 3306 to host machine 3306

```
ports:
 - 3306:3306
```

Exposing container's 3306 to network

```
expose:
 - 3306
```

Comment: `expose:` doesn’t do much on modern Docker.  The port will be reachable from other containers on the same Docker-private network whether you expose it or not.  It will not be reachable from non-Docker unless it’s listed in `ports:`.

Comment: Interesting, so in this case, if I wanted to access it from the other docker container, would I just point it to 127.0.0.1:1344 or would I have to use some internal docker IP?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: each container has their own `127.0.01`, so use `http://e2guardian:1344`. You can refer the other services by the name of the service.