# Unable to connecto to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi i'm start a docker container using docker-compose, but when i try to use localhost to connect I can't connect. Here is the docker-compose i'm using:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  standalone:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar
    expose:
      - 8080
      - 6650
    environment:
      - PULSAR_MEM=" -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g"
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c
      "bin/apply-config-from-env.py conf/standalone.conf
      && bin/pulsar standalone"
```

Im using windows 10

Comment: Try with `ports: 8080:8080` instead of `expose`.Take a look at [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801773/7736617) to see the difference between `ports` and `export`

Comment: What docker environment are you using? `docker-windows`? Could you try accessing it using the ip that `docker-machine ip` outputs.

Comment: when I try docker-machine ip it outputs: Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that `expose`, as the documentation suggest:

> Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be specified.

My guess is that you instead want to publish them and let them be available to the host. To do so:

```
services:

  standalone:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "6650:6650"
```