# How to read / understand a docker-compose.yml and what the "stdin_open: true tty: true" components do?

Tags: docker-compose, yaml

Taking a course that deals with these; the actual specifics is not pertinent to the course, but I generally have interest in trying to understand things regardless.

I have a docker-compose.yml file which I 'call on', or 'spin up'. The file contains the following information:

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - "6379"

  sample0395:
    image: sample0395/base:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    expose:
      - "8888"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
```

From what I understand, and just based on the hierarchy as shown:

- redis and sample0395 are 'services'
- redis:latest and sample0395/base:latest are the image_name:tag combinations
- expose and ports: list the ports (not sure what the difference is or what the significance is of the difference between these two)
- I have no idea what stdin_open or tty do, and cannot seem to get an understanding through google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tty` and `stdin_open` are analogous to the `-t` and `-i` arguments for the `docker run` command, respectively.

You use `stdin_open` when you need to work on a project outside the Docker container.

You use `tty` when you need to work on a project inside the Docker container.

To test this out, try running `docker-compose up` with either `tty` or `stdin_open` but not both and you'll find that with `stdin_open` you don't log in to the container's terminal while the opposite happens with `tty`.

As for your question regarding the difference between `expose` and `ports`, answers are found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801772/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-compose-ports-vs-expose).

Comment: This helps. Could you please share examples of working on a project from outside the container vs inside the container?