# Kibana can't connect to ElasticSearch with docker on Mac M1

Tags: docker, macos, elasticsearch, kibana, apple-m1

Basically I'm trying to setup a environment with elasticsearch and kibana with docker on a m1 mac. I've setup the de env variable `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM`to `linux/amd64`. Everything seems fine on running the container but when I try to connect kibana to elastic they just can't see each other. This is my current `docker-composer` file:

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.3.3-amd64
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - node.name=elasticsearch1
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch1
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128M -Xmx128M"
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - my-network

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.3.3-amd64
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: localhost
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://localhost:9200/
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - my-network
```

Before that I was using `links` insted of `networks`, no luck with that either. From my terminal or browser I can see both elastic and kibana running on their respective ports. I'm without ideas here, appreciate any help!

EDIT
docker ps output

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                               NAMES
265023669cfd   docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.3.3-amd64                 "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp              folha3_kibana_1
48ee37663dda   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.3.3-amd64   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp    folha3_elasticsearch_1
6b1f6dd9473f   redis                                                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp              folha3_redis_1
2a3ade65634a   mysql:5.7                                                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   folha3_mysql_1
```

Comment: can you share the output of `docker ps` in the terminal

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast I've updated the question with the output

Answer (score 0):

`ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://localhost:9200/` should be `http://my-network:9200/`, `localhost` can't access elasticsearch container.

Comment: Makes total sense, I changed to it but it still doesn't work.

```Failed to open TCP connection to my-network:9200 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)```.

Comment: Also changed to ```ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS``` According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006139/7047663)