# When I specify ports in a docker-compose.yml file, is it TCP or UDP?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know that I can specify the protocol of "ports" in the `docker-compose.yml` file, but I am unsure what the default protocol is, if no protocol is specified.

Is it TCP? Is it UDP? Both?

I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere (including in the Docker Compose file reference).

Comment: Presumably TCP. Didn't test myself, I just [cribbed it from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801773/4137916). See also [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32958). The Dockerfile (not compose) docs also note that TCP is the default throughout for the `EXPOSE` section and port parameters, so compose doing the same would be consistent.

Comment: The default is TCP.

Comment: And if I want both? Do I specify the same port twice with different protocols?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

by default TCP is used, you can see it launching `docker-compose ps`

If you want to specify you should add /udp or /tcp like :

```
ports:
  - "80:80/udp"
  - "80:80/tcp"
```

Comment: And what if I want both? Do I then add two records for the same port range?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Yes, however be aware of [this currently open issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7627)

Comment: Just for future records (or the link breaks) the open issue is now fixed (1.29.2) and the above format should work as expected.

Comment: Why is it not in the official documentation of docker compose https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose ?

Comment: It's in the doc here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports
You are confusing expose with ports, here you will have some clues : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801773/4035371

Answer (score 3):

In addition to above comment for me docker compose long syntax worked to open UDP port, do also check that your required port is open and available to cater request.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

```
ports:
 - target: 18123
   published: 18123
   protocol: udp
   mode: host
```