# Why a service configured with only `expose` is able to communicate with internet?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

Something confuse me about docker networking. I've a `docker-compose.yml` file which can be simplified like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    foo:
        ...
        networks:
            - main_network
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
    bar:
        ...
        networks:
            - main_network
        expose:
          - "5000"
networks:
    main_network:
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801773/5075502), `expose`...

> Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be specified.

If this is true, `bar` should only expose the 5000 port to `foo` service. And It seems to work as expected. If, I run `bash` into `bar` service and execute:

```
$ ss -lntu
```

The 5000 port is opened correctly:

```
Netid    State     Recv-Q  Send-Q   Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port
...
tcp      LISTEN    0       128      0.0.0.0:5000          0.0.0.0:*
...
```

As expected, from outside of my container, using a web browser for example, I cannot connect to this host. Also, If I run

```
$ nmap -p1-65535 127.0.0.1
```

I can verify that **only** the 3000/TCP port of `foo` service is opened:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3000/tcp open  ppp
```

So, what I don't understand is that IRL, my `bar` service is able to connect to Mongo Atlas online or ping internet. How does it get it's answer if the ports aren't Exposed/Opened in order to receive it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The answer to which you have linked is old and incorrect.

1. The `EXPOSE` keyword is primarily a no-op. It's informative ("this image will offer services on these ports"), but it doesn't have any operational impact.

   In older versions of Docker, the `EXPOSE` keyword could be used for service discovery by linked containers, but (a) it still didn't have any operational impact -- the ports were available whether or not there was a matching `EXPOSE` -- and container "linking" has been deprecated for a quite some time.
2. Containers have outbound internet access by default. Outbound access is managed with a simple NAT rule in the host firewall `nat` table (and corresponding rules in the `filter` `FORWARD` chain).  E.g., on a system where I am running Docker 20.10.2, in the `FORWARD` chain I have:

   ```
   -A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   -A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
   -A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
   -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   The first rule passes packets that are part of an existing TCP connection. This permits the return packets for your outbound connections.

Comment: Note that the `EXPOSE` keyword,as described in this answer, is in fact deprecated in `Dockerfile`s. But `expose` in `docker-compose.yml` still does its intended function: expose ports to other services. It seems to me that the OP's question is referring to the latter.

Comment: Expose in a `docker-compose.yml` doesn't expose ports to other services: services can access ports in other containers regardless of whether or not you use the `expose` keyword. It really is strictly informational, at best.

Comment: [These docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose) state that `expose` is does the function described (or `ports`, really), and I see no mention in docs that services have access to each others' ports. Is the behaviour you describe documented? I'm asking to learn, not disputing your expertise. I'm not in a position to fire up a test right now.

Comment: "ports" is used to expose container ports on the host. Neither "ports" nor "expose" is required for containers to access each other (as long as they are on the same network). This is basic Docker behavior (e.g., there's nothing specific to docker-compose here). I don't know that there is a single place that states all this explicitly, but it's probably covered by various bits of the networking docs (https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/, https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/, etc).

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll get to reading.

Comment: To the first reply... EXPOSE is not deprecated: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/