# Traefik with multiple docker-compose.yml files

Tags: docker-compose, devops, traefik

Hello traefik friends.

I just started to look into traefik. All tutorials show how to run one docker-compose.yml file with traefik togather with other containers. I most often have many separate docker-compose.yml files and very much would like to use them with traefik.

so here is my code for traefik container:

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - "traefik"
      - "external"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

and the other exemplary docker-compose I would like to use with traefik:

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ./php/www:/var/www/html/
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php.rule=host(`php.xxxxxx.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

unfortunately that doesnt seem to work (when I concat theese to files into one big docker-compose.yml file - it works fine. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe this can work for you: docker-compose -f docker-compose-first.yaml -f docker-compose-second.yaml config > docker-compose.yaml && docker-compose up

Answer (score 3):

Each `docker-compose.yml` by default create its own virtual network. So traefik from the `traefik` network can't access PHP server from some other "`php-default`" network.
see [Compose Networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

You have to add the PHP server to the `traefik` network by setting the default network of the `php/docker-compose.yml` to the `traefik`.

`php/docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    # we need to tell the traefik what port is the container listening to
    expose: 
      - 80
    volumes:
      - ./php/www:/var/www/html/
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php.rule=host(`php.xxxxxx.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
networks:
  default:
    name: traefik
    external: true
```

**OR** if you want to have the `php/docker-compose.yml` in its own network, you have to define the `traefik` network in the compose file and add the php service to it:

```yaml
services:
  php:
...
    networks:
      - traefik
...
networks:
  traefik:
    external: true
```

Note I have defined `expose` instead of `port`. The `port` exposes ports on the host which you likely don't want when you are using reverse proxy like traefik. The `expose` act as mere documentation ([see this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40801772/5739006)) that the traefik uses.

Both examples expect there is defined `traefik` network somewhere. So to complete the setup here is `traefik/docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.5"
    container_name: "traefik"
    # ...
    # your traefik setup
    # ...
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - "traefik"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
networks:
  traefik:
```

Answer (score 1):

Traefik needs to be part of the networks for all the services it connects to. For me it works when I set `network: host` for Traefik. (And then you have to remove ports part.)

I do wonder how safe that is, I can't seem to access the admin interface from another machine, so that's good.