# Connecting psycopg2 to dockerized postgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I am trying to connect to a postgreQSL-database initialized within a Dockerized Django project. I am currently using the python package `psycopg2` inside a Notebook in Jupyter to connect and add/manipulate data inside the db.

With the code:

```
connector = psycopg2 .connect(
    database="postgres",
    user="postgres",
    password="postgres",
    host="postgres",
    port="5432")
```

It raises the following error:

> OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address:
> Unknown host

Meanwhile, It connects correctly to the local db named postgres with host as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, but it is not the db I want to access. How can I connect from Python to the db? Should I change something in the project setup?

You can find the Github repository [here](https://github.com/PietroAminPuddu/docker-Django-Redis-PostgreSQL-PgAdmin-Nginx). Many thanks!

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    volumes:
      - web-django:/usr/src/app
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-static:/www/static
    links:
      - web:web

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    restart: unless-stopped

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

volumes:
  web-django:
  web-static:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
```

Dockefile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

**Edit**

To verify that localhost is not the correct hostname I tried to visualize the tables inside PgAdmin (which connects to the correct host), and psycopg2:

The (correct) tables of pgadmin:
[image]

The (incorrect) tables of psycopg2:
[image]

Comment: `host` is either a ip address or a dns name that can be resolved to an ip address. So if you haven't configured "postgres" in your own personal dns, its not going to find it.

Comment: @Shmack I also tried to `docker inspect <postgres_container_name>` and tried to connect both with `Gateway`and `IPAddress`. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm assuming the django project and the database are in the same docker container?

Comment: Yes, different services in same container.

Comment: So you're trying to connect to the database inside a docker container from a jupyter notebook, presumably on a different machine?

Comment: Currently, the jupyter notebook is in the same machine (also same directory of the docker_app project). Then, when I will deploy the website, I will need to (maybe?) expose and publish at same time the postgreSQL in order to connect from outside.

Comment: I think docker has a private ip address that gets created for the container. So what you'll want to do is find that containers ip address and use it as the host in your notebook.

Comment: If you are using the Jupyter notebook on your host machine and it's and not part of the network that your docker-compose is creating and you have `ports: - "5432:5432"` declared on your postgres service, than the postgres instance you are connecting to via localhost:5432 in Jupyter IS the postgres service you have defined in your compose file. the `ports` configuration exposes the service's ports on your local network. See this [helpful graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883938/878272) for the difference between `ports` and `expose`.

Comment: Then, you are suggesting that using `host=localhost` then psycopg2 will access the db inside the postgres image within the container?

Comment: yes because you are connecting to it on your host network.  The hostname `postgres` only applies inside the network that `docker-compose up` [generates by default](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). As a side note you can get rid of all the `links` properties because all your services are already accessible to each other on that default network.

Comment: @THX1138 I added an edit to give more info about the case

Comment: Also, as suggested [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker/issues/46)  by tiangolo: "you shouldn't connect to the Postgres DB with localhost but with the name of the Postgres container". But when I do it, it raise error `OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Unknown host`

Comment: @THX1138 You are indeed correct. After a while, I have decided to delete my PostgreSQL 14 from my apps in my local machine. Then, tried again to connect with `psycopg2.connect('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres')` and now it show me correctly the tables of the postgreSQL within Docker. Maybe, I suppose that both database where on localhost:5432 (with same conf) and were in conflict. But, supposing that one day  I will deploy this docker app, can you give me some insights on how I will modify the `docker-compose.yml` in order to connect from outside with psycopg2?

Comment: Deploying it depends on where you are deploying it AWS, Google Cloud etc. If you just mean connecting from the local machine. you should be able to do localhost:5432 already. But the best way is to just add your jupyter notebook server as a service in your docker-compose. That way you don't even need to connect to postgres on localhost because the notebook is part of the network and thus you can connect like
`psycopg2.connect('postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres')`