# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when trying to open app deployed on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I have a node app using express, and am trying to deploy using heroku.

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import pagesRouter from './routes/pages';
import nconf from 'nconf';

const app = express();

app.use(pagesRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || nconf.get('port');

server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

And this works fine locally to create the server, and serve all the routes I've created.

I've then tried to dockerize this to deploy to heroku by creating a dockerfile, and heroku.yml for this:

```
FROM node:18.12.1
WORKDIR ./
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build
RUN npm prune --production
EXPOSE 6001
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

Looking in the logs of heroku, I can see this is running and starting correctly, however when I try to click on 'open app' to view the app running at `https://www.damp-garden-69923.herokuapp.com/` I get the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached

www.damp-garden-69923.herokuapp.com’s server IP address could not be found.

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but would appreciate any help

Note: I am using the GUI rather than heroku CLI

Answer (score 0):

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801772/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-and-expose-in-docker-compose) in here you shouldn't use expose you should use the ports in you docker compose file.

Comment: It's a heroku.yml file rather than a docker compose, and the EXPOSE is apparently just ignored when using heroku, as heroku passes it's own port as an environmental variable