# is there any difference between docker run command and docker image

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to start sqlserver instance.
When I try with Docker run command I am able to connect to Server instance from local with server as 127.0.0.1 The command goes like below.

```
docker run -d -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<PWD>" -e "MSSQL_PID=Evaluation" --hostname sqlpreview -p 1433:1433 --name mssql-server mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-preview-ubuntu-22.04
```

But when I try to do the same with Dockerfile like below, I am not able to connect to DB with server as 127.0.0.1

```
# Use the official SQL Server 2022 image from Microsoft
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-preview-ubuntu-22.04

# Set environment variables
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD "<PWD>"
ENV ACCEPT_EULA "Y"
ENV MSSQL_PID "Evaluation"
ENV HOSTNAME "sqlpreview"

# Expose the SQL Server port
EXPOSE 1433

# Start SQL Server separately to initialize the database
CMD /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

Am I missing something

Comment: Dockerfile `EXPOSE` does close to nothing; the `docker run -p` option is required.  Also consider that `docker inspect` will show you the embedded password in plain text, and you'll have to recompile the image if you want to change any of these settings.  [What is the difference between ports and expose in docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801772/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-and-expose-in-docker-compose) covers similar concepts.